# Paused journey and activated new version - what happens to paused?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

What happens to the paused journey once I activate a new version of the journey?

It's current staying paused but will it just resume automatically after 14 days and will be finishing or do I need to action anything for it to change the status to finishing?

What happens if I resume the paused journey despite having new version running at the moment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the pause option settings when you paused it.  See the screen capture below.  It will return to finishing if you selected "resume the journey".

We typically try to avoid pausing journeys due to the limited options in the pause functionality. If you need to pause having new Journey entrants enter the Journey create a new version, activate it (the prior version will go into finishing mode) and then stop the new version.  This will allow you full control when to resume the Journey which you'll just create a new version and activate it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!